# Word Wrapping characters

Tags: c#, special-characters, word-wrap

I thought only whitespaces cause strings push to next line but now I was trying something with RichTextBox in WinForm app and I realized that long line was wrapped on some other characters too `(,),!,?` etc.

So question is: **Is there some list of all standard used word wrapping characters?**

I didn't found any yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Unicode® Standard Annex #14—Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/) or UAX #14 as it's known to its friends.

Comment: Ouch quite lot of text :D Ok I will go through it. Thanks

Comment: Ok Ok I surrender, this is much complicated as I thought. There's a ton of rules which I simply can't handle all :D

Comment: There are a lot of writing systems in the world, many of which have rules about line breaks. Reading the highlighted rules **LB1** to **LB31** in section 6 gives about the most concise version.

Comment: Yes I understand, and thanks for closer navigation :)